# Is there a way to view the last game stats?

Tags: team-fortress-2

When viewing the leader board after a team fortress game, it shows the points earned by players during the time that each player has scored since connecting to the server (unless the map is changed, at which point the leader board is usually reset). This means that the leader board usually just shows which players have been connected to the server the longest, rather than actually showing which players performed well during the last match.

My question is then: Is there a way to view the statistics and points earned by players only during the last game?

Comment: I really like the way Halo displays the stats after a game, which is probably why this has been bought to my attention recently, but it's something that's always bugged me.

Comment: It doesn't help you in most cases, but the list of MVP's displayed on round end are the 3 players on the winning team with the highest score in that past round (or top 3 scoring players overall in the event of a draw). This obviously doesn't help you if you aren't on the winning team, or aren't in the top 3, however.

Answer (score 5):

You can check a box in the menu that saves a screenshot of the scoreboard, you can see all the stats on that.

The check-box can be found from the title screen here: **Options** > **Advanced** > **Auto-save a scoreboard screenshot at the end of a map**

The saved screenshots will be stored here: *[Steam Folder]\steamapps[username]\team fortress 2\tf\screenshots*

where:

- *[Steam Folder]* is the directory where Steam is installed (by default *C:\Program Files\Steam*)
- *[username]* is your Steam username

Comment: This won't work for the OP, since if multiple games are played without map changes, the scoreboard only shows cumulative points.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. It's a step in the right direction, but as Raven has pointed out, it's not exactly what I am looking for. I have turned it on tho because it's better than nothing :)